# ZFS Raid1-z replace Disk

Tags: zfs

I inted one of my disk from the lower raid1z setup and i was wondering what is the best way to do it, what a re the steps.

```
    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    Misu                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                              ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F1587B  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F14J7V  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F14JYL  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_W1F1G04F  ONLINE       0     0     0
        scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_W1F1G1H7  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Will the lower command do the trick? do i have to do something more?

zpool offline Misu scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_W1F1G04F

Shutdown and replace drive (i'm replacing the disk in the same slot so basicly the sd* shall be the same, even if is not the same i will change it accordingly)

zpool replace Misu scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_W1F1G04F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct way, except the system shutdown is not necessary.

Comment: Great Thanks, shutdown is necessary in my case since my drives/system are not hotplugs.

Comment: I have noticed that even if i replaced the driver in the same slot and the new drive got the same sdb name the simple replace comand did not worked. I had to use  zpool replace Misu scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_W1F1G04F scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_NewDriveSerialNumber